# C - How to check if user has sent text file to stdin

Tags: c, terminal, text-files, stdin

I'm currently working on my school project and wondered if there is any way to tell if user has written `<textfile.txt` to the terminal.

Like this: `./project <textfile.txt`

My project reads all the lines from the text file to `stdin` and via `scanf` works with them. But when I don't use the `<textfile.txt` "thing", it starts without the data. Instead, I'd like it to write an error and stop the program.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For some reason it didn't show the part with "<textfile.txt"

Comment: @Isha Because that looks like an HTML tag.

Comment: Could you please stop wrecking the formatting?

Comment: Your program does not need to know where the file is coming from. If the use uses file redirection {<} then this file will be redirecting into stdin. All your program needs to do is read from std. If you want to know if they didn't use redirection, then you can check argc, and it will equal 2 if they have specified a file name rather than redirection (since redirection does not count as a parameter). To get the file name in this place, it will be stored in argv[1]

Comment: I'm sorry for the duplication... Didn't look carefully enough. But thanks anyway, helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to detect if your stdin is a terminal.

You could use [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) on `STDIN_FILENO`, e.g. to detect redirection or [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)).

Or (on Linux) [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) `/proc/self/fd/0`  , see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

I recommend accepting some program argument to override such an auto-detection. Read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065).

Be aware that redirection and globbing is done by the shell, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398464/50557).

Answer (score 1):

On unix systems you can check whether `stdin` refers to a terminal:

```
if (isatty(0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "input was not redirected\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```